# Error 20012 (severity 2):Server name not found in configuration files

Tags: t-sql, command-line

Here is my code details

```
Step 1.
/etc/freetds/freettds.conf
[mssql]
host = 192.168.1.10
port = 1433
tds version =8.0
client charset = UTF-8

Step 2
/etc/odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS
Driver = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
Step 3
/etc/odbc.ini
[mssqltest]
Description     = MS SQL connection to mssqltest database
Driver          = FreeTDS
Database        = cakephp_results
Server          = mssql
UserName        = sa
Password        = sa
Trace           = Yes
Port            = 1433
```

I tried to connect sql by command line with the following command:

```
$ tsql -S mssqltest -U sa -P sa
Error 20012 (severity 2):
    Server name not found in configuration files.
locale is "en_IN"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20013 (severity 2):
    Unknown host machine name.
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

Answer (score 4):

You should copy `/etc/freetds.conf` to your home folder with dot before its name like this:

```
cp /etc/freetds.conf ~/.freetds.conf
```

Looks like it searches for config per user, I got the same problem recently.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating freetds.conf file in /usr/local/etc

Answer (score -1):

Creating a `~/.freetds.conf` should work for you. It works fine for me